# Concatenating properties of a resource if they exist in SPARQL

Tags: properties, sparql

Assuming I have triple store where some resources represent persons this way:

```
<http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person8755>
    a                 foaf:Person ;
    foaf:family_name  "Calleja"@mt , "Calleya"@la ;
    foaf:firstName    "Nardus" .

<http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3939>
        a               foaf:Person ;
        foaf:firstName  "Martinj" .
```

As one can see, sometimes the person has a firstName but not a family_name. Is it possible to get one SPARQL query column full name which is made up of name and surname if it exists or name only?

Just for future I fixed it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?firstName 


             ?family_name
                ?name 
WHERE
  {            ?person  a                 foaf:Person  ;
                        foaf:firstName    ?firstName   .
    OPTIONAL { ?person  foaf:family_name  ?family_name . } 
    bind ( COALESCE(?firstName, "") As ?firstName1).
    bind ( COALESCE(?family_name, "") As ?family_name1).
    bind (concat(str(?firstName1),str(?family_name1)) as ?name).
  }
```

Comment: don't add the solution to the question...1) add a dedicated answer and 2) "Accept" your own answer.

Comment: Note that your "fix for the future" doesn't put a space between the two fields, so you'll get `NardusCalleja`, `NardusCalleya`, `Martinj` from your sample data. Using `BIND` as you have is an option but should not be required by any fully SPARQL 1.1 compliant engine.

Comment: Also, I had overlooked that you have *some* lang-tagged strings, which may lead to more output than is desired. That doesn't impact the bulk of this question as written, but I thought it worth raising the flag. There are various ways to address these; which is appropriate depends a great deal on the overall characteristics of your data (are all `foaf:firstName` strings untagged? should `foaf:firstName` be matched with same-lang `foaf:family_name`? etc.), so I won't go into more detail on that here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You don't have a query here, so it's hard to adjust. The basic would be something like --

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?firstName 
                ?family_name
                ( CONCAT ( ?firstName, " ", ?family_name ) AS ?fullname ) 
WHERE
  {            ?person  a                 foaf:Person  ;
                        foaf:firstName    ?firstName   .
    OPTIONAL { ?person  foaf:family_name  ?family_name . } 
  }
```

-- which you can see run live through Virtuoso, on URIBurner.com ([link to query](http://uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FfirstName%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ffamily_name%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20CONCAT%20%28%20%3FfirstName%2C%20%22%20%22%2C%20%3Ffamily_name%20%29%20AS%20%3Ffullname%20%29%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3APerson%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3AfirstName%20%20%20%20%3FfirstName%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20%20foaf%3Afamily_name%20%20%3Ffamily_name%20.%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2025&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000) and [direct link to results](http://uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FfirstName%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ffamily_name%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20CONCAT%20%28%20%3FfirstName%2C%20%22%20%22%2C%20%3Ffamily_name%20%29%20AS%20%3Ffullname%20%29%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3APerson%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3AfirstName%20%20%20%20%3FfirstName%20%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20%20foaf%3Afamily_name%20%20%3Ffamily_name%20.%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2025&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000)).

Comment: Thank you so much...but what if I want to display Martinj in the fullname column as well?

Comment: Have you tested my query? Perhaps you should. It should answer your followup question, by displaying `Martinj ` in the `?fullname` column.

Comment: yes I did and unfortunately it does not display Martinj when only the firstName is provided. It is left empty

Comment: What software are you running as your SPARQL query processor and/or your RDF data store (a/k/a quad store or triple store)?  Note that this has been asked several times on your various questions -- because this detail matters to saying "you've hit a bug" or "that's a known limitation of that software"  or the like. I'm adding a link to a running demo of my query.